# How to display an alert message from .cshtml view - asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two action result one sending a string and another loading the view

```
public ActionResult getTheString()
{
   string message = //doing some thing ;
  myModel myModel = new myModel();
  myModel.property1 = message ;

    return loadView(myModel);
}

public ActionResult loadView(myModel model)

{
   return view (model);
}
```

### loadView.cshtml

```
@model project.Models.myModel 
@{
  if(Model.property1 !=" ")
     {what to do to show it as alert }
}
```

Here I am getting the prperty like `model.property1` if it has some thing show the alert with that string and then load, if message does not contain anything then simply load.

Not permitted to use `TempData` , `ViewBag` , `ViewData`.

Not permitted to use Script tag in view  . it has to be in a seperate js file

Comment: Why not use Javascript in the onready event to display an alert as soon as the page is rendered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check with some simple Razor syntax

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Property1)) {
    <script>alert("@Model.Property1");</script>
}
```

Comment: suppose just an alert(@model.property1) . how can i call that to appear that alert

Comment: its executing (pressing f10) to alert line but alert is not appearing in my view

Comment: Are you sure you have edited "Property1" to your "property1"?

Comment: I just understood partial view wont render alert if its called again  . i did a different approach to solve it

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript and give alert once page is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.load = function() {
    @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Property1)) {
        alert("blah blah");
    }
}    
</script>
```

Comment: my js file is different , it will not read Model.property1 . cant put js script in same view